# How to use Zend_Date to print a time in a specific timezone

Tags: zend-framework, zend-date

In my app I use Zend_Date. I have set date_default_timezone_set('UTC') because internally and in the database I only want to have UTC times.

For users I want to display it in their local time. What is the easiest way to do this? Let's say, I have in the view $user->timezone and $date, where $timezone is 'Europe/Helsinki' and $date is a Zend_Date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be better documented in the manual, as it's a pretty common use case. Fortunately it's nice and easy:

```
$date->setTimezone($user->timezone);

echo $date->get(Zend_Date::TIME_SHORT); //prints in user timezone
```

Comment: It will cause quite some codeclutter if I do this for every date I print in my view. Is there no short method like $date->getByTimezone(Zend_Date::TIME_SHORT, $user->timezone)?

Comment: I would suggest writing a simple view helper for this :)