# Get GMT timestamp using Zend_Date

Tags: php, zend-framework, datetime

I use the following code to get current time stamp. How do I get GMT time instead of local time?

```
$date = Zend_Date::now();
$timeStamp = $date->getIso();
```

Comment: See:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550432/how-to-use-zend-date-to-print-a-time-in-a-specific-timezone][1]
for using Zend_Date::setTimezone()

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550432/how-to-use-zend-date-to-print-a-time-in-a-specific-timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/Zend/Date.php said

```
 * Always set the default timezone: http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set
 * For example, in your bootstrap: date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

If your timezone is different and you still want to get GMT without changing default try this

```
$date = Zend_Date::now();
$timeStamp = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date->getTimestamp());
```